# The configuration section 'uri' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, web-config

I tried to install [BugNET](https://bugnet.codeplex.com/) on IIS7 with .net 4.5

It keeps showing

> The configuration section 'uri' cannot be read because it is missing a
>   section declaration

It is pretty much like this [issue](http://forums.asp.net/t/1839088.aspx) and [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fa54935-56a8-4cf8-990e-9e9f5e183de8/after-publishing-a-package-to-file-the-data-fails-to-load-when-running-in-vs-also-it-runs-the?forum=LightSwitchDev11Beta)  But my app pool was set to 4.0.

And it works fine on IIS8 with .net 4.5

I think the setting were the same.

Any help ? thx

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It turns out it does mean it is missing a section declaration.

I just add

```
<section name="uri" type="System.Configuration.UriSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

inside of `<configSections>`

Then it works fine.

Comment: Make sure the Version is correct based on the version you require. I had to change the version to 'Version=4.0.0.0'

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for the links you've included in your question; the first you've included worked for me, so I thought I'd quote it for the cargo culters who come after:

> When you encounter this issue, please just change the .NET Framework Version of pool to V4.0 in IIS.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1839088.aspx

(I've the URI element, but no `<section name="uri"…`.  I've got no IIS chops, so I can't say anything more on the subject!)