# What are the consequences of running a .Net Core application with an application pool set to a .Net Framework version?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-7.5

TLDR: Are there any negative consequences associated with choosing a .Net Runtime for a .Net Core application's application pool (instead of using No Managed Code)?

--

I have an existing website that has been built on Full-Framework Asp.Net and have just created a .Net Core application to work with it, and it's being hosted on IIS 7.5 on a Win2K8r2 server.

The root IIS site is just www.mydomain.com, but the new .Net Core application is essentially a subdirectory - www.mydomain.com/mynewproject.

When I setup the new .Net Core application, I configured a new application pool with "No Managed Code" selected as the .NET Framework version (as pretty much every tutorial I've read out there has recommended).

However, it appears that if you don't choose .NET Framework v4.0.30319 when using IIS 7.5, you will receive the following configuration error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
Config Error: The configuration section 'uri' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
```

Note that the config file with this error was the root of the site (www.mydomain.com), not my application's web.config.

Researching that particular issue yielded this fix, which has two viable options: [The configuration section 'uri' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871047/the-configuration-section-uri-cannot-be-read-because-it-is-missing-a-section-d)

1. Add uri as a section in the web.config entry. I tried adding it to both the root site (www.mydomain.com) and the application (www.mydomain.com/myapplication) and it didn't help
2. Change the Application Pool to .Net v4.x (this did resolve the problem)

So I have found a solution and it seems to be working, but I don't know if there are any negative consequences of selecting a .Net runtime. Is it just extra overhead?

Comment: Does the web server have the ASP.NET Core Module installed? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module

Comment: Yes, I have another .Net Core application installed and running well as a separate website on the same server. This problem appears to be isolated to running an application as a sub application of a website running on full framework.

Comment: @GageTrader did you ever find any further negative consequences associated with choosing a .Net Runtime for a .Net Core application's application pool?

Comment: @RyanBuening I have noticed, at least running on IIS 7.5, that the application was extremely slow to load when it hadn't been accessed for awhile. I deployed it to Azure and it ran very smoothly out of the gate, so I think it had something to do with IIS 7.5 or my specific configuration. In any event, I came across an article that mentioned preloading applications: http://cdn.rssbus.com/help/ARC/mft/pg_serveriis7dot5.htm (very last section). Other than that, I haven't experienced any other problems. Note that the site in question is dead simple - no complex logic going on.

Comment: @GageTrader thanks for the update.