# The configuration section 'webFarms' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: iis

i issued new SSL certificate and install it on the server but when i assign it to the default (localhost) for testing i get the below errors

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module     ApplicationRequestRouting
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code     0x80070490
Config Error       The configuration section 'webFarms' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
Config File    \\?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\DefaultAppPool\DefaultAppPool.config
```

anybody can give me solution ??

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with your certificate. This message alone indicates the relevant component (ARR) might not be installed properly. You might try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, please try to create a `‘webFarms’` section declaration inside of `configSections`, or delete and recreate it again.
[https://forums.iis.net/t/1191686.aspx?WFF+2+2+Missing+Section+Error](https://forums.iis.net/t/1191686.aspx?WFF%202%202%20Missing%20Section%20Error)
Besides, incorrect application pool settings can also cause this problem, please just change the .NET Framework version of pool to `V4.0` in IIS.

> When you encounter this issue, please just change the .NET Framework
>   Version of pool to `V4.0` in IIS.

See these links for more details.
[The configuration section 'uri' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871047/the-configuration-section-uri-cannot-be-read-because-it-is-missing-a-section-d/21925390)
https://forums.asp.net/t/1839088.aspx